# How does a computer follow the BODMAS rule?

Tags: python, operator-precedence

Given a simple arithmetic expression i.e.,

```
3+2*5-6
```

When calculated using python as the language

```
>>>3+2*5-6
7
```

As has been taught to us in our schools that in the given expression

1. We first solve 2*5 i.e., 10
2. We then add the result to 3 i.e, 13
3. Finally we subtract 6 from the result i.e., 13-6=7

I wonder how does the computer approach this expression even without specifying the brackets?

Comment: Python follows PEMDAS/BODMAS just like you learned to in school. However, I still suggest using parentheses/brackets for readability/debugging.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: @all_readers This is a first question and doesn't require a downvote.

Comment: To be clear to the OP, the "computer" itself does not necessarily use bodmas as you describe. In fact, it almost certainly doesn't but there is a program between you and the "computer" that accepts your sum and applies the rules that you understand to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: First before reading the answer make sure to have the light theme for Stackoverflow in order to see the images clearly.

## Parse Tree

A parse tree is a tree data structure which can be used to represent real-world constructions like sentences or mathematical expressions.

[image]

Representing a sentence as a tree structure allows us to work with the individual parts of the sentence by using subtrees.

[image]

We can also represent mathematical expressions which is the answer to how python manages to maintain operators precedence (BODMAS), We know that multiplication has higher precedence than either addition or subtraction. Because of the parentheses, we know that before we can do the multiplication we must evaluate the parenthesized addition and subtraction expressions. The hierarchy of the tree helps us understand the order of evaluation for the whole expression. Before we can evaluate the top-level multiplication, we must evaluate the addition and the subtraction in the subtrees. The addition, which is the left subtree, evaluates to 10. The subtraction, which is the right subtree, evaluates to 3. Using the hierarchical structure of trees, we can simply replace an entire subtree with one node once we have evaluated the expressions in the children.

And if you want to know more about the implementation part and how can you write a parse tree you can check this article (http://www.openbookproject.net/books/pythonds/Trees/ParseTree.html).